# Are questions about non-specific computer hardware on topic?

Tags: discussion

Is the following question on topic?

[What laptop specs are important for intensive image editing work?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/33973/what-laptop-specs-are-important-for-intensive-image-editing-work)

> How important is the following in purchasing a laptop that will be used for image editing:
>
> - processor speed
> - amount of RAM
> - integrated vs. dedicated graphics card
> - HD speed (SSD; or 5400/7200/10000 rpm)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's okay. It's not my favorite question, but, eh, they can't all be. :)

1. It's about resources for use in a photography workflow
2. It asks what's important, not which one to buy

Specific numbers for processor and RAM will be outdated quickly, but the relative value of each is a longer proposition. Even the difference between smartphone pictures and high-end DSLRs doesn't really change that equation.

I respectfully think that the edit @dpollitt suggests tends towards making it *much* more localized, as the software versions will go out of date quickly and the combination of camera, habits, and software will necessarily match many other people. (Test: would it be useful to have a different question identical in all of the particulars, but with Lightroom 4 changed to Lightroom 5?)

It *is* kind of broad, but even then the class of things one does with photographs *does* narrow things down. It's different from the needs for software development or for gaming or even for video editing.

Comment: I think I'm just annoyed when people start talking about SSD and RAID on a photography website. Not that I don't do all of that(and FOR my photography), but it just has nothing to do with going out and taking a photo with a camera to me.  People like to endlessly debate this stuff all over the net and every context wildly different than photography.

Comment: I am standing by with an upvote waiting for your "none of that really matters" answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I see a few potential problems with this question as it stands:

**Too localized** - The question specifically asks about processor speed and ram, which obviously will quickly date answers. "Specific moment in time" is the localized aspect here.

**Not a Real Question** - The original question notes no specific software being used, image sizes, catalog size, OS preference, etc. It is overly broad, and can easily turn into a debate since the question is so wide open.

**Not Constructive** - The answers already have turned into extended discussions since nearly every technical person on this site has an opinion on computer hardware.

I know that some people disagree with my "problems" outlined above. I think that the question *could* be salvaged with the proper edits from the OP. For example what if the question was:

> I currently have a 6 year old under-powered laptop. I am looking for a new one to edit Nikon D800 RAW images. I commonly shoot 2,000 photos or so per month. I will be using Adobe Photoshop CS6 and Adobe Lightroom 4 to edit photos. What type of graphics card should I look for to get the best performance?

So without edits, I think that it should be closed. With edits, I think it can be on-topic and useful to some photographers. Without edits this question is just as applicable to someone on stackexchange.superuser or a similar site, since we have no idea if the user is editing smartphone pictures or Nikon D800 pictures, 100kb or 10GB, Gimp or Photomatix Pro, etc.

Comment: It would really depend on the answers provided. It is possible to answer such a question rather generically, such that it is useful to the most people for the longest time: **Get as much horsepower as you can that will last you for as long as you require.** ;) In my experience, photo editing tools are increasingly becoming massive resource hogs, to the point where you need almost as much horsepower as a fairly powerful gaming rig to keep things moving fluidly. This issue is exacerbated by larger screens, and seeing as larger screens greatly improve post processing workflow...